# proof for a problem in propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I cant find a proof for given problem:

$$p \to ( q \to p)   ≡   \lnot p \to ( p \to q )  $$

Please give proof to prove above statement.

Comment: Truth tables are acceptable?

Comment: No i am sorry.:)

Comment: The answer depends on the axioms you have chosen.  If you want a formal deduction of a proposition, you have to begin with a set of axioms (assuming you have also a established a proof system).

Comment: ya i got it , but i need proof carried from L.H.S and moving finally to R.H.S

Comment: @KidA424: You can go the other way and analyze what it takes to work out. The left hand side is a constructive tautology ([proof being](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BHK_interpretation) $λ(x:p).λ(y:q).x$) and so it's true in any logical system that has a name. The question then asks what it takes for the right hands side to always be true. By uncurrying to $(¬p\land p)→q$ we see its an internalization of [the principle of explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). So the claim won't be true in [paraconsistent logics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic).

Answer (score 1):

We have :

> $$p → ( q → p) \equiv \lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor p)$$

by [Material Implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_%28rule_of_inference%29) twice,

> $$\equiv (\lnot p \lor p) \lor \lnot q$$

by [Commutativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and [Associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property),

> $$\equiv (T \lor \lnot q) \equiv T$$

by [Negation laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) : $p \lor \lnot p \equiv T$ and [Identity laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) : $T \lor p \equiv T$,

> $$\equiv T \lor q \equiv (p \lor \lnot p) \lor q \equiv p \lor (\lnot p \lor q)$$

by *Identity laws, Negation laws* and *Associativity* again.

Finally :

> > $$\lnot p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$$

by *Material Implication* twice.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the possible truth values for (p,q) and check that the two formulas output the same value in the 4 cases.

If you want an axiomatic proof you can do this:

Since $a\to b$ is a notation for $\neg a\vee b$, we can unfold the first formula into $\neg p\vee (\neg q\vee p)$. This is actually equivalent to $true$, since $p\vee\neg p$ is always true. You can do the same with the other one, and so by showing they are both tautologic, you get that they are equivalent.

Comment: yes it is valid, i have done it

Comment: i m  using to check whether problem is right

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $\neg(A\wedge\neg B)$ and also to $\neg A\vee B$. Use De Moivre and transform both formulas in a disjunction of conjunctions.

Comment: @NikolajK, true. but the method works even when both sides aren't tautologies.

Answer (score 0):

$p\to q$ and $\sim p$ can be substituted with $1+p+pq$ respectively $1+p$, where $pq$ is short for $p\wedge q$ and $+$ is exclusive or. Therefore:

$(p\to(q\to p))\equiv 1+p+p(q\to p)\equiv 1+p+p(1+q+qp)\equiv 1+p+p+pq+pqp\equiv 1$, since $r+r\equiv 0$ for all $r$.

and

$(\sim p\to(p\to q))\equiv ((1+p)\to(1+p+pq))\equiv 1 +(1+p)+(1+p)(1+p+pq)\equiv$ 
$1+1+p+1+p+pq+p+pp+ppq\equiv 1$

Alternatively, prove that $p\to(q\to p)$ and $\sim p\to(p\to q)$ both are tautologies.

Comment: ya i got it , but i need proof carried from L.H.S and moving finally to R.H.S

Answer (score 0):

The following is a proof of the result using a Fitch-style proof checker:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/